# How to deduce this version of Doob's Inequality?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Usually the Inequality is written assuming that $X$ is a submartingale, but in this book, $X$ is a supermartingale.

Here's the statement:
[image]

My doubt is concerned with the terms involving $X_v$ in the first two inequalities.

1. In the discrete version of the first inequality, we would have $E(X_0)+\sup_nE(X_n^-)$. Here, I don't understand how the $sup$ becomes the $E(X_v^-)$, even after having taking the limits from an increasing sequence of discrete sets $J_n$ such that $lim_n \sup_{j \in J_n}E(X_j^-)=\sup_{j\in [u,v]}E(X_j^-)$. Being $X$ a supermartingale, I would have expected the $\sup$ to be bounded from above by something involving $E(X_u)$ instead...
2. In the second inequality, instead of $E(|X_v|)$, we had again $\sup_nE(X_n^-)$. However, if I understand how to do point 1, then since $X^-\leq |X|$, I think I immediately have the second inequality...

In an answer, now deleted, a user suggested to use the fact that $f(x)=x^-$ is a concave and decreasing function, together with Jensen's inequality. However, with this I've only been able to prove that $E(X_n^-)\leq (E(X_n))^-\leq (E(X_v))^-$

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong... $f(x)=x^-$ is not concave, but convex.

Here's a picture. [image]

Using this, we have $(E (X_n))^-\leq (E (X_v))^-$ by $f$ being decreasing. And now by Jensen, we have $(E (X_v))^-\leq E(X_v^-)$.